# Any way to filter Language in Red Dead Redemption? Is it online?

Tags: red-dead-redemption, xbox-360

I personally don't care for foul language.  But the game looks great!

Is there anyway to enjoy the game without the language?

Does the bad language find its way into the online version (ie from the game its self not the other online players.)  If not, I could just play online and not worry about the single player mode.

Comment: You're willing to kill people in the game, but don't want them to swear at you?

Comment: @Beska - Well, the killing is not a real as the swearing.  If I shoot someone in the head with a shotgun, in real life I am going to see more than a small spray of red (that looks more like a can of spray paint than a real gunshot wound).  However, the language is real to life....

Comment: Violent gun death and boobs etc fine, spicy language somehow a no-no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to filter out the language in the game at all. I am trying to recall if there is any swearing in the online cutscenes, and I don't think so, but I'm also rather inured to it, so I may be misremembering. The online cutscenes for the hideouts tend to be only direct explanations of what you have to do, nothing story related, so I think mostly swearing free, except maybe for some "go kick some ass!" or something. Online play is very different than the single player mode though, as there is nothing related to the story at all online. It's mostly Free Roam or clearing out hideouts with other people.

Comment: Is it still worth buying the game if you are only going to play online?

Comment: @Vaccano: I'd say yes. The online part of the game is pretty fleshed out and a lot of fun. There's coop missions that give you more than just the Free Roam Hideout clearing, as well as competitive modes (team deathmatch, capture the flag, king of the hill, etc). And as you do more stuff there's more things to unlock for the look of your character and titles and challenges. There's a lot of game in the multiplayer portion.

Comment: I would say that it would depend on if you have a group of friends that you can posse up with regularly or not. Grouping with random people can be reeeeeeeal hit or miss. More than once, I would get random posse invites only to map travel to the leader and have them kill me. If you have friends to play with so you can avoid PUGs, it's a blast.

Comment: I hate when that happens.
@everyone If you want to play online in serious and help each other to get PS3 multiplayer trophies add me: ALFADORMX